# Increment div class by +1 on click

Tags: javascript

I'm sure this is an easy question but I cannot figure it out.

I basically have a div with a number, 'div-1' for example, and need to +1 to the number every time another div is clicked. e.g. 'div-2' 'div-3' etc..

Comment: mind putting some code or at least what language this is in?

Comment: What is your specific question? Where are you stuck?

Comment: What is the original task you're solving? having `div-1` ... `div-3` classes looks suspiciously at first place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say a div with a number, It should be on `id` attribute.

```
<div class="your_div_selector" id="div-1">
```

so, in your javascript, using jquery and when the other div is clicked, just do this:

```
var div_id = $('.your_div_selector').attr("id")
var new_id = 1 + parseInt(div_id.split("-").pop());
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you've described, it looks like you have an HTML `div`, which starts with a class of `div-1`. Every time the div is clicked, you want the `div-n` class to be replaced with a `div-(n+1)` class.

This is easily accomplished with an `onclick` listener.

```
<div id="mydiv" class="div-1"></div>
<script>
var mydiv = document.getElementById('mydiv');
mydiv.currentClass = 1;

mydiv.addEventListener('click', function() {
  mydiv.classList.remove('div-' + mydiv.currentClass);
  mydiv.classList.add('div-' + (++mydiv.currentClass));
});
</script>
```

Note that there should be a better solution, depending on your specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="yourDivClass" id="myDiv"></div> <button id="incriment" onclick="incrementDivClass()">Click</button>

function incrementDivClass()
{  
    var divIncriment = ($('.yourDivClass').length);    
    $('#myDiv').append('<div class="yourDivClass" id="div-'+divIncriment+'">div-'+divIncriment+'</div>') 
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sm60yLgu/1/)